# How can I seamlessly extend disk for bitcoin-core full node?

Tags: full-node, pruning, storage

I'm running a bitcoin-core full node and serve customers wallet service (e.g. creating a wallet, sending tx). I set the chain data disk size to 400GB when first setting the node up and the disk is almost full now.

I'd like to increase the disk size without halting or stopping wallet service. Can I get advice or tips for doing it?

I'm using a cloud service for running the node and it's highly likely to stop `bitcoind` process if I increase disk size on the cloud console. (I don't think `bitcoind` can write to disk while the cloud service working on the disk)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a question for your hosting provider; you should ask if they support online disk resizing. It has nothing to do with Bitcoin Core.

Comment: I understand what you mean. My question was more about finding workaround while disk is not read/write-able. I think I'm gonna spin up another instance and export wallet to the new node.

Comment: This is a question for general system administration, and is not Bitcoin-specific.